# Store Lovefilm streaming movies with Sony SMP-N200

Tags: media-player, video-streaming

I have a Sony [SMP-N200](http://www.whathifi.com/review/sony-smp-n200) Media Streamer, which I want to use with the [LoveFilm](http://www.lovefilm.com/) streaming service.  The streamer has no storage that I'm aware of.

How can I cache film downloads on another device so that I don't get cut off before the end of the film?  Caching on a home NAS would be great.  I realise that the DRM will expire the movie - I'm only want to ensure I see the whole film!

If the service is an issue, then Netflix would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't!

http://www.lovefilm.com/help/dyn_faqs.html?faq_cat=watch_online&editorial_id=9342